# Html radio button, why does only the ones with correctAnswer value set to true gets toggled on?

Tags: html, angular, radio-button, tailwind-css

I am using angular and this is my home.component.html file.

```
<div class="pt-10 h-screen">
  <div class="flex flex-wrap h-5/6">
  <div *ngFor="let card of cards" class="w-1/1 md:w-1/3 lg:w-1/5 p-2 h-1/2">
    <div *ngIf="card.question=='';then nil else notnil" class="h-1/1"></div>
    <ng-template #nil></ng-template>
    <ng-template #notnil class="h-full">
    <mat-card class="h-full">
    <mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-title>{{decode(card.question.toString())}}</mat-card-title>
      <mat-card-subtitle>Type: {{card.type}} , Difficulty: {{card.difficulty}}</mat-card-subtitle>
    </mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-content>
      <div *ngFor="let answer of card.answers" class="">
        <!--<button mat-button color="primary" class="quiz-option-button" (click)="getAns(answer.correctAnswer,card.question)" fxFlex="100" [innerHtml]=answer.answer></button>-->
        <input class="p-4" type="radio" value="true" (toggle)="true" (click)="answerValue=answer.correctAnswer" >{{answer.answer}}
      </div>
      <button mat-raised-button (click)="getAns(card.question)" type="submit">Submit</button>

    </mat-card-content>
  </mat-card>
    </ng-template>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h1 class="w-screen text-8xl">Score: {{count}}/10</h1>
</div>
```

Here is a structure of card in cards

```
{
  "question": "Who voiced the character Draco in the 1996 movie &#039;DragonHeart&#039;?",
  "type": "multiple",
  "category": "Entertainment: Film",
  "answers": [
    {
      "answer": "Brian Thompson",
      "correctAnswer": false
    },
    {
      "correctAnswer": true,
      "answer": "Sean Connery"
    },
    {
      "answer": "Pete Postlethwaite",
      "correctAnswer": false
    },
    {
      "answer": "Dennis Quaid",
      "correctAnswer": false
    }
  ],
  "difficulty": "medium"
}
```

I am unable to toggle any radio whose answer.correctAnswer is false.
I dont now why this occurs but i need it to work on radio inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Just changed the value of correctAnswer to 1 where true and 0 where false and changed its type to number